# MySql SELECT from table1 if column in table2 = 1

Tags: mysql

I need to return a column from `table1` if a column in `table2`, which has the same identifier with a different column name, has a `1` in a specific field.

**table1**

[image: table1]

**table2**

[image: table2]

In this example I would like to retrieve `item_code` `222` from `table1` where `alt1` is `888`, but only if `alt1` is `1` for `item` in `table2`.

I've tried numerous inline queries and `LEFT JOIN` variants but nothing seems to be able to actually perform the task.  Writing out all the versions I've tried is pointless as none of them have worked, but an example would be:

```
SELECT item_code FROM table1 WHERE alt1 = "888" 
AND (SELECT item FROM table2 WHERE item = "222" AND alt1 = 1)
```

The above is probably not the best example of something I've tried, but since none of them have worked so far it doesn't really matter.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT item_code from table1 INNER JOIN 
table2
ON table1.item_code = table2.item where table2.alt1 = 1 and table1.alt1 = 888
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 3):

You can use JOIN clause :

```
SELECT t1.item_code 
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.item_code = t2.item AND t2.alt1 = 1
WHERE t1.alt = 888
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT item_code FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 
       ON t1.item_code = t2.item_code
WHERE t1.alt1 = "888" AND t2.alt1 = 1
```

?